# For the differential equation does the existence/uniqueness theorem guarantee that there is a solution to this equation through the point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

For the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{y^2-25}$ does the existence/uniqueness theorem guarantee that there is a solution to  this equation through the point

1. (-1,28)
2. (0,5)
3. (3,-5)
4. (1,34)

given that $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)=\sqrt{y^2-25}$

$f'=\frac{2y}{\sqrt{y^2-25}}$

this means as existence and uniqueness  theorem the interval containing 5 is not have solution i am right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On solving the differential equation, we get
$$\ln|y+\sqrt{y^2-25}|=x+c$$
Now if you put the $4$ points here, do you get real finite values of $c$?

Comment: ,...yes all points give finite value of c

Comment: @Psuresh So your solution exists for each point.

Comment: ....3 point getting negative sing of ln is that mean ther is no solution exist

Comment: Don't forget the modulus sign .. you only take the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compute the complete solution by first noticing that $y\equiv \pm 5$ are constant solutions and that under the substitution $y=5\cosh(u(x))$ for $y>0$ the equation transforms to
$$
y'=5\sinh(u(x))u'(x)=5|\sinh(u(x))|
$$
so that $u(x)=x+c$ for $u(x)\ge 0$. This allows to patch solutions together,
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases}
5&x<c,\\
5\cosh(x-c)&x\ge c.
\end{cases}
$$ 
Similarly for $y<0$ one finds the solutions
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases}
-5\cosh(x-c)&x< c,\\
-5&x\ge c.
\end{cases}
$$

In short, if the task also includes the "uniqueness" part of the existence and uniqueness theorem, then you get a different selection of choices that apply.